# Can't access phpmyadmin on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I'm on my way to learn laravel and trying to access to phpmyadmin and get that error

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: So where did phpmyadmin get installed? ...and is the port correct? ... it should be whatever the `DocumentRoot` location may be. Also, double check the folder name, as it might be named: `phpMyAdmin` or possibly with a version, such as: `phpMyAdmin-x.x.x`, or some other naming convention. If that is ok, then make sure that the port is 80, and not some other config such as 8080, or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem that I installed laravel and installed lamp  that and the apache was running so I had to stop apache and run lamp by those two commands

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```